# Puppet: build DNS file from node config (or: how do I iterate over node variables globally)

Tags: bind, puppet, ruby, puppetmaster

I also use puppet for my nodes. I am also running a (BIND) dns server.

Would it be possible to use the `$aliases` variable I have for each node in a template for the DNS module?

My nodes look like this:

```
$ cat nodes/kayak.local.pp
node 'kayak.local' {
  include base
  $node_aliases = ['svn','puppet']
  $node_primaryip = '10.0.64.200'

  network::interface { 'eth0':
    ip      => $node_primaryip,
    gw      => '10.0.64.1',
    mac     => '00:50:00:00:00:3f',
    netmask => '255.255.255.0',
  }

}
```

What I am looking for is being able to make a template like this:

```
$cat local.erb

<% scope.lookupvar('ALLNODES::aliases').each do |alias| -%>
<%= alias %> IN A <%= node_primaryip %>
<% end -%>
```

who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use exported resources for that.

- create a defined type that manages a line in your dns file
- on each host, create a resource that uses that defined type. Use @@ before the type to make it exported.
- Collect those resources on your DNS server with the spaceship operator.

Sidenote: use Hiera for all that data in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks. Had to do some searching there. I think I understand what I need to do. Haven't read about hiera though. Would that make solving my 'problem' easier?

Comment: Hiera is pretty awesome in seperating data from your code...
- http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html